# show that $F''$ is strictly increasing.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

> If $f$ is continuous and always positive in $[0,\infty)$ and $$F(x)=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^x(x-t)^2f(t)\,dt$$then show that $F''$ is strictly increasing.

I found that the integrand is continuous and so , $F$ is differentiable and $F'(x)=0$. But to show $F''$ is strictly increasing we have to show that $F'''(x)>0$ in $[0,\infty)$. How it is possible ?

Comment: Using $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{a}f(t)dt = \int_{0}^{a}f(a-t)dt$May be it is helpful to you

Comment: $F'''(x)=2f(x)>0$ and we are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$\begin{align}
F'(x)&=\int_0^x 2(x-t)f(t)dt\\\\
F''(x)&=\int_0^x 2f(t)dt\\\\
F'''(x)&=2f(x)>0
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 5):

Expand the square:
$$2F(x)=x^2\int_0^xf(t)dt-2x\int_0^xtf(t)dt+\int_0^xt^2f(t)dt$$
Differentiate:
$$\begin{align}
2F'(x)&=2x\int_0^xf(t)dt+x^2f(x)-2\int_0^xtf(t)dt-2x^2f(x)+x^2f(x)\\
&=2x\int_0^xf(t)dt-2\int_0^xtf(t)dt
\end{align}$$
Divide by two and differentiate again:
$$F''(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt+xf(x)-xf(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$$
And again:
$$F'''(x)=f(x)>0$$

Comment: This way is slower than others but it doesn't use any theorems about integration of functions on several variables.